# AWS - Cannot release Elastic IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I am trying to release Elastic IP addresses from my AWS account.
**I do not have any EC2 instances running.**
When I select the EIP rows from the table in the console and click "Release Elastic IP address," I get the following error message:
[image]

The problem is that the "Disassociate Elastic IP Address" menu is grayed out, meaning I may not have any living objects to disassociate from.

From the table of Elastic IP addresses, I cannot figure out what objects may need to be removed in order to release these EIP addresses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to remove a network interface that's hanging around. Check to see if your elastic IP is associated with any of your network interfaces.

Here's how to check with us-east-1 as an example:

https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#NIC:

Change [us-east-1] to the region you use.